# delete duplicates from a sorted multi 3 elements array using indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to store 200 choices from 3 players in an array in groups of three ex [1,4,3],[2,1,5]....

Afterwards, I need to delete the duplicates, and since in JS we cannot compare 2 arrays I was thinking in comparing the indexes inside the 3 choices single array after sorting the array and push the ones who are equal to a new array. I dont know why this is not working. Any ideas?

```
var choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var player1 = [];
var player2 = [];
var player3 = [];
var store = [];
var unique = [];

for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  player1.push(choices[i]);
  player2.push(choices[i]);
  player3.push(choices[i]);
}

function values() {
  for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var rand1 = player1[Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length)];
    var rand2 = player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)];
    var rand3 = player3[Math.floor(Math.random() * player3.length)];
    var choice = [rand1, rand2, rand3];
    store.push(choice);
    store.sort();
  }
  for (j = 1; j <= store.length; j++) {
    if (store[j][0] == store[j + 1][0] && store[j][1] == store[j + 1][1] && store[j]
      [2] == store[j + 1][2]) {
      unique.push(store[j]);
      console.log(store);
    }
  }
}

values();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` method can be updated to store strings (3 numbers concatenated into one) instead of array of number in a `Set`

```
function values() {
  var store = new Set(); //set instead of array
  for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 
    var rand1 = player1[Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length)];
    var rand2 = player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)];
    var rand3 = player3[Math.floor(Math.random() * player3.length)];
    store.add(rand1 + "-" + rand2 + "-" + rand3); //add value to set, set will remove duplicates automatically
  }
  return [...store].sort().map(s => s.split("-").map(t => +t)); //convert set to array, sort that array and convert the string to array of numbers
  //convert to set
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var player1 = choices.slice();
var player2 = choices.slice();
var player3 = choices.slice();

function values() {
  var store = new Set(); //set instead of array
  for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var rand1 = player1[Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length)];
    var rand2 = player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)];
    var rand3 = player3[Math.floor(Math.random() * player3.length)];
    store.add(rand1 + "-" + rand2 + "-" + rand3);
  }
  return [...store].sort().map(s => s.split("-").map(t => +t));
  //convert to set
}

console.log(values());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you are sorting `store` instead of `choice` in each iteration.

And another way to compare the `arrays` is to convert them to `strings`, and check for their existence in the `array`, then remove duplicates and convert them back to an `array`.

This is how can be your code:

```
function getUniqueValues(arr) {

  //Convert the sub arrays to strings
  arr = arr.map(function(a) {
    return a.join(",");
  });

  //Remove duplicates
  var result = arr.filter(function(subArray, pos) {
    return arr.indexOf(subArray) == pos;
  });

  //Convert back the strings to arrays
  result = result.map(function(a) {
    return a.split(",").map(Number);
  });
  return result;
}
```

And in the end of your `values` function call it like this:

```
unique = getUniqueValues(store);
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo using this function in your code:

```js
function getUniqueValues(arr) {

  //Convert the sub arrays to strings
  arr = arr.map(function(a) {
    return a.join(",");
  });

  //Remove duplicates
  var result = arr.filter(function(subArray, pos) {
    return arr.indexOf(subArray) == pos;
  });

  //Convert back the strings to arrays
  result = result.map(function(a) {
    return a.split(",").map(Number);
  });
  return result;
}


var choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var player1 = [];
var player2 = [];
var player3 = [];
var store = [];
var unique = [];

for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  player1.push(choices[i]);
  player2.push(choices[i]);
  player3.push(choices[i]);
}

function values() {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var rand1 = player1[Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length)];
    var rand2 = player2[Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length)];
    var rand3 = player3[Math.floor(Math.random() * player3.length)];

    var choice = [rand1, rand2, rand3];
    choice.sort();
    store.push(choice);
  }
  unique = getUniqueValues(store);
}

values();

//console.log(store);
console.log(unique);
```